# Save image from Unity camera with post-processing effects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, post-processing

I have a separate camera from my main camera, whose purpose is to take screenshots at different angles.  Hierarchy as such:

[image]

- The main camera captures the 3D scene just like a normal main camera would, including post-processing components.
  [image: Post-processing components]
- The GUI camera captures just the UI layer.
- The canvas and image are simply a watermark, rendered by the GUI camera.

I point both the main camera and GUI camera to the same target render texture.  The result of the render texture appears to be correct in the inspector.

[image: Render texture is correct]

Then I convert to a normal Texture2D so it can be saved:

```
RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
destination.ReadPixels(new Rect(0f, 0f, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
destination.Apply();
```

When I look at the resulting texture in the inspecting, the appears correct.  But if I look at the thumbnail of the resulting texture, then it only shows what I presume is the bloom.

[image: Bright colors opaque, dark colors transparent.]
(On black so it's easier to see.)

I have also tried AsyncGPUReadback.  Its resulting texture looks like a flat gray without variance in the inspector.

Regardless of how I convert the render texture to a regular texture, the resulting PNG on disk only has the bloom in it.

[image: Bloom only.]
(On black so it's easier to see.)

I have found if I disable post-processing, everything works as intended, no changes required.  Of course, I am missing the post processing, which I want!

EDIT: Upon further research, it appears that Unity's Encode methods are drawing upon something external of the texture itself, causing it to save the wrong data.  If I use a separate PNG encoder using the same Color32 data, everything works as intended.

I am still curious what the "correct" way of doing this is, though I have a way forward at least.